# zmq_connect() a socket while waiting for a zmq_send() or zmq_recv()

Tags: multithreading, zeromq

I'm working on an application where I want to use ZeroMQ to connect nodes of different types which may be added and removed while the system is running. This means that I want to call `zmq_connect()` or `zmq_disconnect()` at any time as nodes come and go.

Some connection use sockets of type `ZMQ_REQ`, which block when no peers are available. Thus, it may happen that one node is blocked in a zmq_recv(), without any node available for processing the request. If then a new node becomes available, I would like to connect the socket using zmq_connect(). The only way I can see how I could do that is to call zmq_connect() from a different thread. But the documentation states pretty clearly that `zmq_socket` instances cannot be used from multiple threads simultaneously.

How can I solve this problem, sending messages on a `ZMQ_REQ` socket without any connections (or connection which cannot be established) and then later add connections and have the waiting requests being processed?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `zmq_recv()` when no messages are ready. That way you avoid blocking your thread. Instead check that there indeed are a message to receive. The easiest way to achieve this is using a `poller`. Since you haven't stated which library or language you're using I can't give you the right example, but I guess C example from the ZeroMQ Guide's examples [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/c:mspoller) could be of use.

Building ZeroMQ based applications is, in my experience, most effective by building one threaded nodes that reacts to messages and, if necessary, runs methods based on time intervals.

For building a system like you talk about I suggest you look at the [Service Discovery](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Service-Discovery) chapter of the awesome [ZeroMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all).

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you. I was using pyzmq for that project and tried using a `poller` and a local connection between threads to wake up the ZMQ thread but didn't get it to work reliably. Probably I or pyzmq messed something up related to global state. I will soon redo the project with the stdlib's `asyncio` and probably just use something like [aiozmq](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiozmq) and not bother with the details. :)